# what i am missing in this simple jquery code

Tags: jquery

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</head>

<BODY>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   

    $('#shareButton').click(function(){
        alert ("this is hit");
    });
});


</script>
<button id="shareButton" > Share </button>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

On clicking button, it is not alerting the message "This is Hit".

Please help .. Thanks

Comment: Your button tag is nested inside your script tag... It shouldn't be.

Comment: From the comments you probably edited the code, but it does seem to work just fine - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Znnwr/) -

Answer (score 3):

Move your button out of the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `<button id="shareButton" > Share </button>` from `<script>` tags.

Comment: Its typo.  <button id="shareButton" > Share </button> is not in <script > tag

Comment: Move button outside the `<script>` tag and it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/WZdFJ/ I can't see other problem.

Answer (score 1):

Move your button of the `<script>` tag. because The button tag is inside script tag, it should be outside.

Answer (score 0):

Your button element is inside the `<script>` tag. Put it before or after the script section.

Answer (score 0):

The button tag is inside script tag, it should be outside.

Answer (score 0):

```
hi there but above code is working in on my side,
```

i am using firefox 13.0.1 browser code running it self. 
if you unable to see the result kindly check out whether
 or not the jquery file u included properly or not check 
your internet connection is working so that file from google get included in your html page. And kindly put the script in the head section and button in body section of html